# Joomla curly brackets code with jquery

Tags: jquery, joomla

So I am using a plugin for social sharing (jabookmark), and I want to render that code always in a specific position, instead of always writing in the joomla article the code "{jabookmark}", I want to auto insert with jquery, but then joomla doesnt load the plugin but renders just plain text. Here is the code that I am using:

```
jQuery('.article-content').find('div.author').after('{jabookmark}');
```

Any solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you will be able to do it like this. The the problem being is that the PHP which is converting the short tags and then processing the plugin is being done before any client side code gets process. Therefore you're inserting `{jabookmark}` but it isn't getting processed. One thing you can try is creating a small custom plugin and importing your jQuery code using the `onBeforeRender` event. I'm not 100% sure if this will work as I haven't tested it but worth a shot.

Hope this helps